# .NET Reflection PropInfo.GetValue() in a static context

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection, datacontext

I am stuck with a weird problem

Let me show you my code

```
private static void OnMyCustomPropertyChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = e.GetType().GetProperty("PropName");
    String propName = propInfo.GetValue(?,?).ToString();
}
```

The problem is, what do I mention in place of the two question marks, the second parameter is null as far as I know since it is not an indexed property. When I use propInfo/propInfo.GetType().GetProperty("PropName")/sender, in place of the first "?", I am getting an exception - TargetException was unhandled by user code.

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this along with an explanation if possible. I would like to understand where I am making the mistake.

Comment: `propInfo.GetValue(e,null)`? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter must be the instance you want to get the value from.

In your example, you should pass `e` as parameter, because you're getting a property of the `e` object.

That being said, I suspect you want the property of the `sender` instance instead:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = sender.GetType().GetProperty("PropName");
String propName = propInfo.GetValue(sender, null).ToString();
```